# TinyMCE Custom plugin -- button doesn't appear

Tags: wysiwyg

I am trying to create a custom plugin for TinyMCE 3.5.9. I have a module that is adding it to the WYSIWYG profile, which can be checked. That works. But when I load a page, the custom button does not appear on the WYSIWYG.

The plugin is there in the background though, and I can even fire it in the console using this command:
tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mcePullQuotes');

So the code is being loaded and initialized. Just the button is not appearing. Been banging my head.

This code is pretty much cribbed from the example code in the Jscript/plugins example, and I don't see much different going on in other plugins. There are no console errors.

```
(function() {
  tinymce.PluginManager.requireLangPack('pullquotes');    
  tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.PullQuotesPlugin', {
    init : function(ed, url) {

      tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mcePullQuote');
      ed.addCommand('mcePullQuotes', function() {
        ed.windowManager.open({
          file : url + '/dialog.htm',
          width : 480 + parseInt(ed.getLang('style.delta_width', 0)),
          height : 340 + parseInt(ed.getLang('style.delta_height', 0)),
          inline : 1
        }, {
          plugin_url : url, // Plugin absolute URL
          some_custom_arg : 'custom arg' // Custom argument
        });
      });

      ed.addButton('pullquotes', {
        title : 'PullQuotes',
        text: 'PQ',
        cmd : 'mcePullQuotes',
        icon: false,
        image : url + '/img/example.gif'
      });

    },

    getInfo : function() {
      return {
        longname : 'Pull Quotes plugin',
        author : 'Adrian Cotter',
        authorurl : 'adrian.cotter@sierraclub.org',
        infourl : 'http://www.sierraclub.org',
        version : "1.0"
      };
    }
  });

  tinymce.PluginManager.add('pullquotes', tinymce.plugins.PullQuotesPlugin);
})();
```

UPDATE:

So one problem was this... I had this in my module code, which is where the button was showing up in config from, and how the code was being loaded.

```
'extensions' => array(
  'internal_name_of_myplugin' => t('Example'),
),
```

BUT... I removed that and replaced it with this

```
'buttons' => array('pullquotes' => t('Pull Quotes')),
```

This appears in the profile config -- but nothing is loading now. No button, and no JS this time. Path does not seem to be an issue.

Comment: No console error?

Comment: There are no console errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the button working. Through 2 things in my module.

1. `'buttons' => array('pullquotes' => t('Pull Quotes')),`
2. `'path' => 'sites/all/libraries/tinymce_plugins/pullquotes',`

It seems that the various methods I was using to get the path, were giving the whole URL /sites/all/libraries/tinymce_plugins/pullquotes
So when I put it in as an absolute, and then removed the proceeding / everything worked.